# normal force on a physical pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, harmonic-oscillator

I have read and understood that a normal force has got nothing to do with torque on a physical pendulum. But I can't understand in which direction the normal force points to. Can someone help?

[This image](http://s33.postimg.org/q1tb4pgun/image.jpg) is confusing me. Please help.

This image. Can you explain the direction of normal force in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Normal force in a compound pendulum (physical pundulum) system?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24537/)

Comment: This seems to impart some knowledge. But I still can't understand the image. Please help

Comment: Ignore... comment deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the image either. But I'm going to guess that the pivot of the pendulum is taken to be at rest. In that case, the normal force takes on whatever value is needed to achieve zero net force on the pivot (so that it does not accelerate).

Comment: There's no other force... It's like a nail hammered into a wall. What if the same is directed to top left? That way it could counter the mg force right?

Comment: And one more thing.... It's not the value... It's the direction am confused about